# Python/Pandas Conditional multiple column division (Example code)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Having a DataFrame like this:

```
type  A  B  total
1     4  5   9
2     5  5  10
1     4  1  5
```

Is it possible to apply this code:

```
df[['A','B']] = df[['A','B']].div(df['total'], axis=0)
```

BUT based on a condition, what I mean is apply it only if type == 1 while leaving the other values (type == 2) unchanged and without modifying (subseting) the dataframe as a result of the division?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Boolean mask; in fact, [`pd.DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) works here:

```
cond = df['type'].eq(1)

df[['A', 'B']] = df[['A', 'B']].mask(cond, df[['A','B']].div(df['total'], 0))

print(df)

   type         A         B  total
0     1  0.444444  0.555556      9
1     2  5.000000  5.000000     10
2     1  0.800000  0.200000      5
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand the condition *without modifying (subseting) the dataframe as a result of the division*, but I would do this with a `loc` statement, applying the division only to rows with `type == 1`:

```
df.loc[df['type'].eq(1),['A','B']] = df[['A','B']].div(df['total'], axis=0)
```

Giving you:

```
>>> df
   type         A         B  total
0     1  0.444444  0.555556      9
1     2  5.000000  5.000000     10
2     1  0.800000  0.200000      5
```

Where the values for `type != 1` are unmodified, except that they are floats instead of ints (because those columns are of dtype float after division). If this goes against your condition, please let me know in comments, and I'll delete or modify this answer!

Answer (score 1):

Using `update`

```
df.update(df.loc[df.type==1,['A','B']].div(df['total'], axis=0))
df
Out[417]: 
   type         A         B  total
0     1  0.444444  0.555556      9
1     2  5.000000  5.000000     10
2     1  0.800000  0.200000      5
```